# Position: sticky polyfill for angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, polyfills

Are there any polyfill available for angular 2 position:sticky. I have been able to find a few, but most of them are jquery based, there seem to be no implementation available for angular 2:

https://github.com/wilddeer/stickyfill

I need to know the sample usage with angular 2,

for Javascript it is as follows:

```
var stickyElements = document.getElementsByClassName('sticky');

for (var i = stickyElements.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    Stickyfill.add(stickyElements[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I added it as a directive on angular 1.4 and npm package "stickyfilljs":"^2.0.3"

```
import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import * as Stickyfill from 'stickyfilljs';


@Directive({
  selector: '[StickyPolyfill]'
})
export class StickyPolyfillDirective {

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    Stickyfill.addOne(this.elementRef.nativeElement);
  }
}
```

And in the component I have:

```
<div class="top-bar-container stickyMenu" StickyPolyfill>
```

Don't forget to include sticky in CSS:

```
  .stickyMenu {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: -moz-sticky;
    position: -o-sticky;
    position: -ms-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0px;       
  }
```

Comment: Can confirm this works with stickyfilljs: ^2.0.3, angular 5 and angular material. Works in MS Edge, IE 10, and IE 11, and of course Safari, Firefox and Chrome work out of the box. IntelliJ doesn't seem to recognize `position: -moz-sticky;
    position: -o-sticky;
    position: -ms-sticky;` Don't know if this is valid or not. Nonetheless, Thanks Igor!

Comment: NP Eric. I think position: -webkit-sticky; etc. are used for older browser versions as some of them use different naming for the same thing. So I added them just in case. See https://caniuse.com/#search=sticky for details

Comment: I published an angular 2+ directive for this here - https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-stickyfill

Answer (score -1):

It has nothing to do with Angular. What you are looking for is a Polyfill to handle something not implemented in a browser, this is not directly linked with jQuery or Angular, it's only linked to your browser.

The one you linked is good, just add it to your build process or to your assets array if you are using Angular-CLI.

You can use it just by declaring the variable as any element, add this to the start of one of your ts file:

```
    declare var Stickyfill: any;
```

Comment: So, can you tell me, how this can be implemented in angular 2

Comment: It does not have to be implemented?

Comment: I mean to say, how it could be used in angular 2 application

Comment: I just need to know the usage in the angular 2 component